# How to use JGit to get list of changed files?

Tags: jgit, git-log

Using JGit, I want to get a list of files changed on commits as is possible with git log --name-status.

Is this possible? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 3):

I use a modified version of the JGitUtils from the great [GitBlit-Tool](http://gitblit.com/):

Look at the [source of the method](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gitblit/utils/JGitUtils.java#L718) `getFilesInCommit` to see how this can work (`PathChangeModel` is just used to hold the data.)

Comment: That link goes directly to the master branch so the target line moves around.  Here's a [more durable link](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/3e0c6ca8a65bd4b076cac1451c9cdfde4be1d4b8/src/main/java/com/gitblit/utils/JGitUtils.java#L917) that goes to a specific commit hash so it won't change over time.

Comment: @TimMattison, thanks. Github should really have an easy "permalink".

Comment: What do you do with `DiffStatFormatter.java`? Is there any update to this question?